# SharePoint COM retrieving list data from site and sub-site on the same page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to access list data from site and several levels of sub-sites in one page.
I have searched the web and tried to apply few solutions found here on Stack Overflow but to no avail.
This is the simplified code I am using.

```
// parent-level 
var clientCtx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 

getListItems(listName, camlView,fields, clientCtx);

//sub-site level
clientCtx = new SP.ClientContext(subSiteUrl);
getListItems((listName, camlView,fields, clientCtx);
```

This code works for the parent site but not for sub-sites.
The client context passed inside getListItems function for sub-site contains the right URL and seems to instantiate all objects: web, list, listItems, etc., but fails to enumerate list items with the "Unknown error". The same thing happens for both sub-sites i have tried.

```
function getListItems(listName, queryString, fields, clientCtx)
{
web = clientCtx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);       
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
query.set_viewXml(queryString);
var listItems = list.getItems(query);

query.set_viewXml(queryString);
var listItems = list.getItems(query);
var fieldList = fields.join(",");

clientCtx.load(listItems); 

clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
var resultItems = [];
var listItemEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();                          

     var fieldValues = listItem.get_fieldValues();
     var resultItem = {};                           
     for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
          resultItem[fields[i]] = listItem.get_item(fields[i]);
     }
     resultItems.push(resultItem);
}
return resultItems;
}
...
```

}